# Macro Code to Number Lines based on if there is Data

Tags: vba, excel

I am newish at VBA but I cannot figure out how to make this work. I am copying a ton of data from a another Excel sheet and then deleting the unneeded rows. The problem is that I need my data numbered in column A and when I delete the row it skips numbers. I want a macro that will number my data after I delete the unneeded lines. I do need it to stop when my data stops but the number of lines will be different each time. Any tips? Thank you.

Comment: Why copy then delete? Why not just copy what you want? In any event, if you show the relevant code then it would be easier for us to suggest how to improve it.

Comment: Just add a formula in Column A to display the row number if there's data in an adjacent cell. No need for VBA. Or even type "1" in the first cell and auto-fill

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this...

After deleting rows, run the following code which will add the sequence number in column A starting from row2.

```
Sub SqNumber()
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
With Range("A2:A" & lr)
    .Formula = "=Row()-1"
    .Value = .Value
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use union  method.  You collect range and at the last line,  delete them.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngU As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 100
        If Range("a" & i) = "" Then
            If rngU Is Nothing Then
                Set rngU = Range("a" & i)
            Else
                Set rngU = Union(rngU, Range("a" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rngU.EntireRow.Delete 'rngu is collected ranges.
    End If
End Sub
```