# Delete all but one row based on two column values in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and want to remove rows from an Excel file. I want to remove a row that has a Status 'Completed', but only if there is at least one more row remaining for a CustomerName. In other words, if there is only one more row remaining for a certain CustomerName, it should not be deleted, even though it might have Status 'Completed'.

I figured out how to remove rows if they have Status = 'Completed':

```
Sub RemoveAlmostAllCompletedRows()
Dim i As Long

i = 1

Do While i <= ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 18).Text, "Completed", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Else
    i = i + 1
End If

Loop

End Sub
```

This removes all rows that have 'Completed' in column 18 (Status column). Now I am really stuck finding a way to prevent a row with Status = Completed, if that would delete the last remaining row for a CustomerName.

Any ideas or tips to get me going?
Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928753/macro-code-to-number-lines-based-on-if-there-is-data/44929356#44929356)  union method is fast and simple.

Comment: @Dy.Lee Did you read the question? Fraukje, in combination with the `instr`, also use `application.worksheetfunction.countif()` on the CustomerName column to ensure the value is >1. Also a note on deletions and loops. When deleting ideally you want to loop in reverse, as deleting i technically makes i+1 the new i. you could do `for var = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count to 2 step -1`

Comment: @Zerk,  In large data, your method is slow.  Union method collect range, and at one time delete all range. It is very fast.

Comment: @Dy.Lee You're really not understanding the question. Union is faster for deletions as it is only a single transaction and I'd recommend it in most cases. It is not compatible with the question. Assuming a customer has 3 completed orders, all 3 would get deleted as the countif would return 3 for each test due to the rows not being deleted until the end. Deleting individually ensures that when only one remains it is kept.

Comment: @Zerk, you are right. But questioner's explanation seems to be lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `WorksheetFunction.CountIf`.  Considering that the column `A:A` is the one containing the customer names and worksheet `Sheet1` is the sheet you're working in:

```
Sub RemoveAlmostAllCompletedRows()

    'You should always define precisely your worksheet
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim i As Long
    i = 1

    Do While i <= WS.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

        If (InStr(1, WS.Cells(i, 18).Text, "Completed", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
            If (Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WS.Range("A:A"), _
                WS.Range("A" & i).Value2)) > 1 Then

                WS.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete

            End If
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me towards the CountIf function. Also, showing me that worksheet definition is required is much appreciated!

Comment: @Fraukje; My pleasure and thanks for your comment.  In fact, worksheet definition is not "required" but it is a best practice that will help you avoid a lot of future problems.  You could check **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/2687063)** for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Place the below line inside the first `IF` block as another `IF` block before deleting the row.

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,10).EntireColumn),ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,10).Value) > 1 Then
```

This will count the customer names and only call delete line if there is more than 1. I made assumption customer name is in column 10. Change as needed.